# Restoring the Dump using PostgreSQL's psql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to restore the DB from an SQL file using

```
psql dbname < dumpfile
```

but after I connect to my DB psql provides a prompt with the name of the database to which psql is currently connected, followed by the string =>. For example:

```
testdb=>
```

So how can I enter the command, or which Meta-Command should I use to restore the DB with the psql command? (Already connected to my DB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`psql` is the command line client. You cannot call `psql` when you are already in an interactive `psql` session.

Either you connect with `psql -d testdb` in an interactive session and import the dump with `\i dumpfile`, or you stay on the shell and call `psql` in a non-interactive session with the dump file as script: `psql -d testdb -f dumpfile`

Answer (score 0):

you can use \c <database_name>
it will connect you to the desired database

for example

```
global=> \l
      List of databases
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding 
    test     | pgadmins | UTF8  

global=> \c test
You are now connected to database "test" as user "user1".
test=>
```

Comment: I have already connected to my DB. Apparently,
'''
        \i <filename>
'''
seems to work for me, testing it right now.